# MYSQL: char field gets truncated in select statement

Tags: mysql, string, varchar, truncate, string-length

I have a MySQL query that looks like this:

```
select 'abcdefghij' as stringvar
....
union select
select 'aaaaaabbbbbfffffkkkkkk' as stringvar
...
union
select 'ghghgjk' as stringvar'
....;
```

stringvar gets truncated and I'm trying to figure out how to prevent it. Is there a way to specify the length in the select statement?

Thanks in advance!

coco

Comment: Truncate in select?Are you sure this isn`t a client display problem?

Comment: I can't reproduce this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18ee8/2

Answer (score 0):

You can `CAST(<String> AS VARCHAR(MAX))`

Comment: the syntax cast('abcdefghijklmnop' as varchar(500)) does not work.

Comment: Doesn't work in what way?  Does it give an error or the strings get truncated?

Comment: I get an error. But I think it is a display problem in the end.